# Best way to show an inner submenu on mobile website?

Tags: usability, website-design, mobile

On my mobile website I have a menu for the main website navigation. When you are in your account area, this is a further submenu, which is accessed by clicking the second burger menu button.

[image]

The submenu appears like like this:

[image]

However some feedback I got from some users was that they didn't know where the account area options were (I personally thought / still think this is obvious enough).

So is there anything I can do differently here to make it more obvious?

Comment: Are you using two hamburger menus (main and sub one)? Do you actually need two hamburger menus?

Comment: Yes there are two hamburger menus. The main menu contains links to different areas of the website and then the menu in the account area contains account area specific links. I don't think it makes sense to put the account area links in the main menu because it will make it more crowded than it already is, and also users don't always need to see those links.

Comment: How many options do you have in the first and second hamburger menus? I will need more info to be able to help you with a better design.

Answer (score 3):

It may seem obvious to you because you're the one designing it, but here's why your end users don't think it's obvious enough:

- The second hamburger icon that's sitting next to "Your Dashboard" title does not appear to be a navigation button, but more of a decorative icon to indicate where the user currently lands at.

Why you shouldn't use the hamburger icon to achieve the goal:

- **Inconsistency**: Hamburger is a ***navigation*** icon (refer to [this Android Design Guideline](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#anatomy) as an example). In your case, you want to allow users to ***perform actions*** such as changing their personal details or deleting their account.

Instead, there are a few (non-exhaustive) alternatives you can opt for:

- Setting icon

  [image]
- Meatballs icon to indicate actions, as shown below:

  [image: Horizontal and vertical meatballs icon]
- Use a profile thumbnail (display dropdown menu on click):

  [image]

  This is for illustration purposes only. You can use the profile picture of your user instead.

Comment: So are you saying, for example that Settings icon should appear instead of the hamburger icon and submenu? And it should open another page with those actions listed?